# How do I find the value of $CATALINA_HOME?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have to copy `Connnector/J` JAR in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`  of Tomcat7 on `Amazon EC2`. How to find the full path of `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` on Amazon Linux in Amazon EC2?

Comment: Do you have access to the linux console? can you execute "set" command to list environment variable values?

Comment: @AleZalazar `Yes` I can do that.

Comment: did echo $CATALINA_HOME not work?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Tomcat can tell you in several ways. Here's the easiest:

```
 $ /path/to/catalina.sh version
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
Server built:   Jul 3 2012 11:31:52
Server number:  7.0.29.0
OS Name:        Mac OS X
OS Version:     10.7.4
Architecture:   x86_64
JVM Version:    1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720
JVM Vendor:     Apple Inc.
```

If you don't know where `catalina.sh` is (or it never gets called), you can usually find it via `ps`:

```
$ ps aux | grep catalina
chris            930   0.0  3.1  2987336 258328 s000  S    Wed01PM   2:29.43 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dnop -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/lib -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/Users/chris/blah/blah -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/chris/blah/blah/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

From the `ps` output, you can see both `catalina.home` and `catalina.base`. `catalina.home` is where the Tomcat base files are installed, and `catalina.base` is where the running configuration of Tomcat exists. These are often set to the same value unless you have configured your Tomcat for multiple (configuration) instances to be launched from a single Tomcat base install.

You can also interrogate the JVM directly if you can't find it in a `ps` listing:

```
$ jinfo -sysprops 930 | grep catalina
Attaching to process ID 930, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 20.8-b03-424
catalina.base = /Users/chris/blah/blah
[...]
catalina.home = /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29
```

If you can't manage that, you can always try to write a JSP that dumps the values of the two system properties `catalina.home` and `catalina.base`.

Comment: Maybe update to:
"ps aux | grep catalina.home" for better highlighting in the terminal.

Comment: But... if i knew where /path/to/catalina.sh is or I knew how to start it, I wouldn't search where it is?

Comment: It's in `/usr/local/tomcat9` that redirect to /usr/local/apache-tomcatxxx for those (like me) who want to repair a broken installation

Answer (score 0):

Just as a addition.
You can find the Catalina Paths in

> ->RUN->RUN CONFIGURATIONS->APACHE TOMCAT->ARGUMENTS

In the VM Arguments the Paths are listed and changeable