# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, neo4j

I have jsp webapp that works fine when I run it in Tomcat 8.5 on my localhost but when I put it up on a server I get the *Cannot load driver* exception.

(In case it should do any difference the server is an Ubuntu 16 running on Amazon EC2)

I have checked that the jar is in the home/lib folder.
The user running tomcat has the rights (my jstl jar works).
I have tried to reload the deamon and restart the service.

I have been looking around the plethora of threads on this subject but cannot find the right answer (even though I am sure it is out there).

This is my (relevant) context:

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/MyDB"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="myname"
        password="mypass"
        driverClassName="org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost"
        maxActive="8"
        maxIdle="4"/>
```

(name and password is obviously not the real one)

This is the code from the class that exposes the error:

```
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context webContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) webContext.lookup("jdbc/MyDB");
        con = ds.getConnection();
```

This is my stacktrace:

```
Unfortunately something went wrong. This to be specific:
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver'
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2145)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2037)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
at myapp.model.neo4j.LoginHandler.login(LoginHandler.java:24)
at myapp.control.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:27)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2136)
... 28 more
```

Comment: When you say it is in `home/lib`, what do you mean with that? The driver (and all necessary dependencies) should go in the `lib` folder of tomcat (also called `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496280/how-do-i-find-the-value-of-catalina-home

Comment: When I say home I refer to (what should be) $CATALINA_HOME/lib. Will check that post out to see if there is something fishy about the path.

Comment: Running $ ps aux | grep catalina I get -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat. Exactly where I have my lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the proper neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.0.1.jar.

(not some other file with a similar name like neo4j-jdbc-3.0.1.jar)